# React Native updating single property of nested object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am attempting to update a single property of a nested state object and return it to the state. I have the index of the object that I need to update but I am struggling to change one property and add the new object back to the state.

My state object looks like this and I am trying to reduce the lives of a player on a button press.

I have been playing around with using array filter, trying to copy the object and add it back into the state but this then loses the objects position.

```
this.state = {
  players: {
    {id: 1, lives: 3, name: something},
    {id: 2, lives: 3, name: something}
  }
}
```

```
public removeLife(id): void {
   const player = this.state.players[id];
   player.lives = player.lives - 1;
   this.setState({players[id]: {...player}
   })
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I found that the best way to update a single object within a nested state is to shallow copy the state, change the object then re-assign the shallowed state object back to the state. Like this:

```
    public removeLife(event, id): void {
    const newState = Object.assign([], this.state.players);
    const indexOfPlayer = newState.findIndex(selectedPlayer => selectedPlayer.id === id);
    const player = newState[indexOfPlayer];

    player.lives = player.lives - 1;

    this.setState({players: newState})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `state` contains an object of objects I suggest you yo make it an array of objects :

```
this.state = {
  players: [
    {id: 1, lives: 3, name: something},
    {id: 2, lives: 3, name: something}
  ]
}
```

you need to handle update like this (update player in index 1 for example):

```
this.setState({
    players: {...this.state.players, 
       players[1]: {...this.state.players[1], lives: this.state.players[1].lives + 1 }
    }
})
```

or try it (i follow your function):

```
public removeLife(id): void {
   const player = this.state.players[id];
   player.lives = player.lives - 1;
   this.setState({players: {
       ...this.state.players,
       players[id]: {...player}
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: That was a typo, I currently already have an array of objects. I can get the correct index of the object I want to update by using players[1] but the update part doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Really does not  like the way the setState part is formed. Not sure if this is a typescript issue or not?

Comment: I edited again and added your function if it's not working tell me why and what happened after setState

Comment: Unexpected token, expected "," (52:23)

  50 |         this.setState({players: {
  51 |                 ...this.state.players,
> 52 |                 players[id]: {...player}
     |                        ^
  53 |     }
  54 |     })
  55 |     }

Comment: You right! i forgot something - change it to `[players[id]]: {...player}`

Comment: Looks correct now! However... Different error: undefined is not an object (evaluating player.lives)

Comment: I think your id is out of range (0-1 in this case)